# Combining rows of a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of the format:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "10"  "719" "99"  

[[2]]
 [1] "10"  "624" "85"  "888" "624" 

[[3]]
 [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
```

I want to merge by the unique value of first element in list, ie.

```
[[1]]
 [1] "10"  "719" "99" "624" "85"  "888" "624" 

[[2]]
 [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
```

Is there a way to do this with the least memory use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

```
x <- list(c("10",  "719", "99"),
          c("10",  "624", "85",  "888", "624"),
          c("1",   "894", "110", "344", "634"))
first_elems <- sapply(x, "[", 1) # get 1st elem of each vector
(first_elems <- as.factor(first_elems)) # factorize (i.a. find all unique elems)
## [1] 10 10 1 
## Levels: 1 10
(group <- split(x, first_elems)) # split by 1st elem (divide into groups)
## $`1`
## $`1`[[1]]
## [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
## 
## 
## $`10`
## $`10`[[1]]
## [1] "10"  "719" "99" 
## 
## $`10`[[2]]
## [1] "10"  "624" "85"  "888" "624"
## 
(result <- lapply(group, unlist)) # combine vectors in each group (list of vectors -> an atomic vector)
## $`1`
## [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
## 
## $`10`
## [1] "10"  "719" "99"  "10"  "624" "85"  "888" "624"
```

**EDIT**: For non-duplicated keys use:

```
(result <- lapply(group, function(x) {
      c(x[[1]][1], unlist(lapply(x, "[", -1)))
   }))
## $`1`
## [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
## 
## $`10`
## [1] "10"  "719" "99"  "624" "85"  "888" "624"
```

Not much additional memory is needed. Except for the resulting list we need to store the results of `as.factor` (number of classes+number of elems in `x`). `split` requires little extra mem - the vectors in `x` are not deep-copied.

As for the performance, for quite a large list:

```
set.seed(1L)
n <- 100000
x <- vector('list', n)
for (i in 1:n)
   x[[i]] <- as.character(sample(1:1000, ceiling(runif(1, 1, 1000)), replace=TRUE))
object.size(x) # 2GB
## 2175165880 bytes
```

I got the following running times on my old Linux laptop:

```
system.time(local({
   first_elems <- as.factor(sapply(x, "[", 1))
   group <- split(x, first_elems)
   result <- lapply(group, function(x) {
     c(x[[1]][1], unlist(lapply(x, "[", -1)))
   })
}))

##    user  system elapsed 
##   4.119   0.001   4.149
```

Seems reasonable, I think.

Comment: Thanks! But "10" is coming twice in the final list... I just want to combine the other elements ... Please help in that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the speed, but here's a `for` loop method (which I don't often use) that kind of illustrates the methodology behind what needs to be done with your list.

```
x <- list(c("10",  "719", "99"),
          c("10",  "624", "85" , "888", "624"),
          c("1",   "894", "110", "344", "634"))  

y <- vector('list', length(x)) # allocate a list at least as long as x

for(i in 2:length(x)){
  if((x[[i-1]] %in% x[[i]])[1]){
    y[[i-1]] <- c(unlist(x[[i-1]]), unlist(x[[i]][-1]))
  } else {
    y[[i-1]] <- x[[i]]
  }
}

z <- y[!sapply(y, is.null)]
z
# [[1]]
# [1] "10"  "719" "99"  "624" "85"  "888" "624"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1"   "894" "110" "344" "634"
```